# tf.contrib.data.prefetch_to_device doesn't result in training speedup

Tags: tensorflow, io, gpu, prefetch

I noticed that with a model I am trying to run, my GPU utilization is only around 30%, and often this 30% utilization alternates with periods of 0% utilization due to I/O. To address the I/O I added `tf.contrib.data.prefetch_to_device` to my code as below:

```
    dataset    = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(self.filenames, "ZLIB", 384 * 1024 * 1024)
    dataset    = dataset.map(parse_func, 6)
    dataset    = dataset.prefetch(6)
    dataset    = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.prefetch_to_device("/gpu:0", 12))        
    #dataset    = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.prefetch_to_device("/gpu:0", 2))        
    #dataset    = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.prefetch_to_device("/gpu:0", 6))        
    self.iterator  = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
```

As you can see I've done a few things while trying to troubleshoot this, including:

- vary the `buffer_size` argument (had no effect on timing: I tried 12, 6, 2, and 1)
- run other jobs on other GPUs in parallel, or not. in either case no effect on training time
- eliminate the `dataset.prefetch` line in case this is somehow interfering with the device-level prefetch (I also tried smaller numbers such as 2 and 1)

I don't see meaningful differences in any of these variations when I time the training. Also, the GPU utilization continues to follow the same pattern, of alternating 0% and 30% utilization. What else should I be trying, and why isn't the use of prefetching to the GPU affecting the performance at all? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: have you tried to do this without using the prefetch(6) operation?
Maybe the CPU is aggressively doing prefetch, which delays placement of batches on GPU? Have you tried with lower numbers other than 6 and 12?

Comment: @kvish thanks for the suggestions. yes I did try it without the prefetch(6) option. I also tried prefetch_to_device with 2 and 1 as the batch size. I will update my post to reflect this

Comment: thats interesting. A couple of things. You may want to use tf.experimental, as tf.contrib.data.prefetch_to_device is deprecated. And I think having the buffer for prefetch  to device as 1 and figuring out what is the optimal parameters for dataset map parallel calls and prefetch buffer size might be a better way to experiment with prefetching to GPU. And is your data already in form of batches? As prefetch in general tends to work much better for batches than single data points!

Answer (score 7):

**If your CPU and GPU are both at <100%**, your I/O are most likely the bottleneck. Try using **larger batch sizes** to optimize I/O to/from the GPU on the cost of greater memory load. **Prefetching** batches to GPU should help resolve this by overlapping the pre-processing of data with downstream computation. Apart from this, you might want to consider monitoring disc load as well, and see if it is getting saturated. Network I/O, *e.g.* when streaming data from any kind of remote host, might also be a problem (*e.g.* streaming TFRecords from AWS S3 or GC Storage buckets).

**If your CPU is at ~100%, while GPU is <100%**, then your CPU is the bottleneck. If you are on cloud, consider moving to instances with larger CPU-count (*CPU is cheap, GPU is scarce*). If you can't increase CPU count, moving some parts of your graph to GPU is an option. However, TF's `Dataset` pipeline  is run entirely on CPU (despite this, [see](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13610)). **Prefetching** might also help here, but the cost of spawning another background thread to populate the buffer for downstream might damp this effect. Another option is to do some or all pre-processing steps offline (*i.e.* prior to training).

**Prefetching**.

- Consider using a more flexible approach than `prefetch_to_device`, by explicitly copying to the GPU with `tf.data.experimental.copy_to_device(...)` and then prefetching. This allows to avoid the restriction that `prefetch_to_device` must be the last transformation in a pipeline, and allow to incorporate further tricks to optimize the `Dataset` pipeline performance (*e.g.* by experimental [overriding threadpool distribution](https://git.codingcafe.org/Mirrors/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/ee40d87af8e6c24e6e84ff64e4932c38d6ccfcf7)).
- Try out the experimental `tf.contrib.data.AUTOTUNE` option for prefetching, which allows the `tf.data` runtime to automatically tune the prefetch buffer sizes based on your system and environment.

At the end, you might end up doing something like this:

```
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.copy_to_device("/gpu:0"))
dataset = dataset.prefetch(tf.contrib.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

**Comparison of performance**.

(*8 CPUs / 1x Tesla P100 / Inception V3 / ImageNet samples / 32-batch*)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my experiments I observed mild a speedup when there was no CPU `prefetch()` before `prefetch_to_device()` (even with buffer size 1) and only with initializable iterator, not one shot iterator. However in combination with upstream Keras 2.2.4 (+ TF 1.13) I still not observe perfectly overlapping memcpy in nvprof visualization. My hypothesis is that there's some problem in Keras.